# How to include vm argument on command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, executable-jar, emr, jvm-arguments

I have a runnable jar that I want to run on AWS EMR. I need to provide a couple of args and a VM arg. How do I do that?

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

How and where do I include vm argument?

I put this in my VM argument on eclipse

```
-Dncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib=/home/gbachani/HDFView-2.11/HDFView-2.11.0-Linux/HDF_Group/HDFView/2.11.0/lib/libjhdf5.so
```

How do I set it up for AWS EMR?

Answer (score 3):

It is:

```
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
```

(see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

So in your case:

```
java -Dncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib=/home/gbachani/HDFView-2.11/HDFView-2.11.0-Linux/HDF_Group/HDFView/2.11.0/lib/libjhdf5.so -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: How do I set it up on AWS EMR??

Comment: I can use System.setProperty("ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib","/home/gbachani/HDFView-2.11/HDFView-2.11.0-Linux/HDF_Group/HDFView/2.11.0/lib/libjhdf5.so"). May be, I need to try this on AWS.

Comment: In the AWS EMR doc, it seems that parameter mapred.reduce.child.java.opts is the one  to use(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-troubleshoot-slow-6.html)